# Portrait to Landscape removed from Simulator in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

I've been trying to test my app on the iPad Pro going between portrait and landscape and for some reason the simulator does not switch... has this issue always been there and you need an actual device or is this a new issue? Thanks!!

Update: hope I don't sound confusing. The simulator switches, but the app doesn't. As you know iPad Pro apps are required to be landscape too, but it doesn't turn landscape on my simulator, the simulator goes landscape but the app is still in portrait.

Comment: Sorry, I confused you, updated the question. And yes, production version of Xcode 9

Comment: No, you didn't need to on previous versions. Because it still goes landscape on the actual device.

Comment: Yeah, with portrait only checked, it still rotates the app correctly on iPad Pro simulators for me.

Answer (score 0):

We did not remove any rotation modes. Are you sure you have your project configured to handle rotation correctly?

Make sure your project settings allow all orientations and that your view controllers are returning the correct supported orientation values.

Comment: Nah, I don't want it to run landscape. But on the iPad Pro it automatically goes into landscape mode no matter what, like it HAS to. I'm just wondering if that's the same for the iPhone X too, and why it isn't doing the same behavior it does on the devices on the simulator?